# ifcopenshell divide elements based on floors

Tags: ifc

I am new to the ifcopenshell lib.
I can get elements info by its type,e.g.

```
ifcFile = ifcopenshell.open("filepath")
walls = ifcFile.by_type("IfcWall")
slabs = ifcFile.by_type("IfcSlab")
#Then do sth I want
```

just wondering can we separate elements based on their floor info?
I checked the doc but found nothing. Could someone give me a hint?
[link](http://academy.ifcopenshell.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try call "IfcBuildingStorey" type

```
floors = ifcFile.by_type("IfcBuildingStorey")
for wall in walls:
  contain = element.ContainedInStructure
  if len(contain) > 0:
     if contain[0].RelatingStructure.Name == floors[x]:
         ##your implementation.
```